# React-leaflet in Next.js - "ReferenceError: window is not defined"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, window, react-leaflet

This is continuously giving `Window undefined error`. What could be the problem? This is not even showing any map. Tried too many solutions including with next.js dynamic package. Didn't work. Could you give me any answer?

```
import React, { useRef, useState } from "react";
import { Map, TileLayer, Popup, Marker } from "react-leaflet";

const attribution =
    '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors';
const url =
    "https://api.maptiler.com/maps/basic-v2/256/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?key=puoG6vOLC4oqJXcum8fR";

const OpenStreetMap = () => {
    const [center, setCenter] = useState({
        lat: 23.729211164246585,
        lng: 90.40874895549243,
    });
    const mapRef = useRef();
    console.log(Map);

    return (
        <div>
            <Map center={center} zoom={9} ref={mapRef}>
                <TileLayer attribution={attribution} url={url} />
                <Marker position={[23.729211164246585, 90.40874895549243]}>
                    <Popup>This is a popup.</Popup>
                </Marker>
            </Map>
        </div>
    );
};

export default OpenStreetMap;
```

Comment: Maybe this might be of help: https://jan-mueller.at/blog/react-leaflet/#nextjs

Comment: i got some error like this, did u had solved this problem?